# Garbage collection in cgo

Tags: memory-management, go, cgo

I have the following code in Go which uses cgo:

```
  func foo() {
       bar := new(C.struct_bar)
       ...
  }
```

Will bar be garbage collected after the function finishes its execution or I need to explicitly call free?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, even though the `struct_bar` is a C type, the memory is allocated by Go, and will be collected by Go.

Any memory allocated in C however is not tracked by the Go GC. The C code should manage this on it's own, but in cases like `C.CString` where Go triggers the allocation, you must manually free the memory with `C.free`.

Comment: A follow-up, if I allocated a C char pointer using point := new(C.char) and then passed it as an argument to a C function which allocated some memory for this pointer, then would this memory be freed by the garbage collector or no?

Comment: @user2424276: `new(C.char)` allocates a single byte, which will be later collected by the GC. If the C function is going to allocate the memory, don't allocate anything in go, just pass in a pointer.